PreAuthorize methods of a specific service class with Spring Security 6
I would like to PreAuthorize all of my service(MyQueryResolver) methods by the custom AuthorizationManager(CustomAuthorizationManager).
I've came up with this code with help of Spring Security 6 docs,  but it doesn't call the check method of the CustomAuthorizationManager:
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    public Advisor preAuthorize(CustomAuthorizationManager manager) {
        return AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.preAuthorize(manager);
    }

}

@Component
public class CustomAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> {

    @Override
    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> supplier, MethodInvocation object) {
        return new AuthorizationDecision(true);
    }

}

@Component
public class MyQueryResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    public String hello1() {   //  <----- PreAuthorize this through the CustomAuthorizationManager 
        return "Hello1, GraphQL!";
    }

    public String hello2() {   //  <----- PreAuthorize this through the CustomAuthorizationManager
        return "Hello2, GraphQL!";
    }

}

Can you help me on this please?
